# mysql value not found

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table and am using php.  I have:

```
mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1");
```

Now this returns an ID if email was found.  However, I want to do something if it does not find $email in the email table column.  How can I recognise when $email was not found and tell php?

Comment: this stinks like sql injection.

Comment: hello gabi...what do yo umean?

Comment: @Gabi Not necessarily. There's nothing in the code to indicate that `$email` is unsanitised.

Comment: have a read here: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php . You should use prepared statements. More details here http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html

Comment: oh sorry, lonesome is correct, Its for my own admin area (non user access) so does not need cleaning...good catch.

Comment: Still, get in the habit of using prepared statements *all* the time. Don't rely on "Oh, only 'good guys' are going to be using this", for three reasons: 1) Temporary fixes have a way of becoming permanent, and in-house code has a tendency to get re-used without proper review. 2) Using prepared statements isn't really any extra effort. 3) It helps catch your own mistakes, not just malicious attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that is required to check if a result was not found is an if statement used with the `mysql_num_rows` function:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1");

$check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);

if ($check2 == 0) {
    // No email found, so show an error to the user
    echo "No email found!";
}
else
{
   // An email address was found, so do something with it here
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[`mysql_query`](http://php.net/mysql_query) returns a result.  You can call [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows) on that result to see the number of rows selected:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // found a result
} else {
    // no result found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that mysql_num_rows check should help.

Answer (score 1):

If `mysql_num_rows()` returns 0, no row was selected because no email matched. http://docs.php.net/mysql_num_rows